# XDebug - PHP script taking along time 5 to 30s to end after last line

Tags: php, xdebug, php-7

I have some scripts running showing a website, and on my macbook, with php 7.1 installed + xdebug, if I don't put an exit at the end of my script, php takes very long to finish executing.

This code works normally:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
// many many code
exit(microtime(true) - $start);
// exits 0.2
```

This code is ending very slowly:

```
<?php
// many many code
echo microtime(true) - $start; // echoes 0.2s

// but the script need about 10.4s to finish (quite long and changing time)
```

I don't have any code after the exit, so it's really the end of my script...

This is not happening on windows nor on linux. What's wrong about my setup?

Comment: You'll need to show more code for anyone to make a determination as to what's going on.

Comment: Even if there is no code after the exit?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no code after the exit ? Are you sure that this file isn't executed because included in another file, in which there could be more code after the inclusion ?

Comment: I read a question about a week ago with similar question. And if I remember correct it was something about cleaning up. Can't find the thread though.

Comment: @ksjohn I put the exit() at the last line of my index.php file: 0.2s / If I remove it : 10s...

Comment: Check if you enabled `xdebug.profiler_enable` this can massively slow down execution.

Comment: That was that, @Mario! Thanks a lot :))

Comment: @HugoH Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my issue by disabling XDebug remote, thanks to @Mario's comment: XDebug was enabled for remote use. Disabling it made my script ends fast again:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
```